# Mounting a shared drive from windows with CIFS

Tags: mount, ubuntu

What I'm trying to achieve is mounting some drives shared on my network (one a Time Capsule, 3 shared drives from a Windows 10 machine) on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu 14.04 with read and write permissions.

I have been able to get the drives to mount by using this:

```
//10.0.1.2/Movies /home/kev/NetworkDrives/Movies cifs username=user,password=password 0 0
```

Obviously using the correct info for username and password.
Using this line in the `/etc/fstab` file achieves mounting the drives.
I am able to read the files and copy them to my local storage but I can not write to the mounted drives and I can not find out what is wrong.
This is new territory for me so your help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do the write as root, or as a regular user?  If a regular user, can you cp something to it via sudo?  This should help determine if the restriction is in the local access mode or on the CIFS protocol.

Comment: Great question. If I attempt to cp normally permission is denied. If I do it with sudo it works.

Comment: Hmm.  Then I would have expected quintablet's answer to work, since the underlying account is authorized.  Not sure why that fails and the other works.

Answer (score 0):

try (add to entry)... `username=user,password=password, file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777`

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  
Unfortunately no success.  
So the entry now reads "//10.0.1.2/Movies /home/kev/NetworkDrives/Movies cifs username=user,password=pword, file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
 0 0"  
The result from a sudo mount -a is [mntent]: line 5 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 7 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 9 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 11 in /etc/fstab is bad

Comment: Ok, didn't think of this earlier, but try adding 'rw' (without quotes) after pword, instead of the file/dir_mode commands.  'rw' stands for read/write.

Comment: Same result I'm afraid. Mounts, can read but can not write.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to see if it mounts:

```
sudo mount -f cifs //10.0.1.2/Movies /home/kev/NetworkDrives/Movies -o username-user,password=pword,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

(I tried to put this in the comments, but ran everything together and was hard to read).  I use this method and it works for me.  I store it in a file (mountMovies for example) and make it executable `chmod +x mountMovies`.

Comment: So I finally got a chance to try this and using this it mounts in the specified location with read AND write permissions!!!!! I can definitely store that as a file, make that file executable and tell it to run at startup. That being said, I need these drives mounted all the time which is why /etc/fstab is handy. What do you do to handle events like my network rebooting or the PC sharing the drives rebooting or some other similar occurrence? I could run a looping program at startup that re-executes those commands every few seconds but that's probably a big CPU suck. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad you got it to work.  You can put the command into crontab to execute daily.  Additionally, since you can put the command into a shell script, you can test if the location is mounted and if so, just exit or if not mount it.